# Is it possible to use the Finite Fields package to define the elements of GF(4) in terms of the irreducible polynomial $P$?

Tags: function-construction, polynomials, finite-fields

I am new to the Finite Fields package and am finding the package tutorial confusing.

I am wondering, if I am working over GF[4], is there a way of finding the elements of GF[4] in terms of the irreducible polynomial.

As $4$ is a prime power $2^{2}$, then we can define the field $GF(4)=GF(2)[X]/P$ where $P$ is the irreducible polynomial in $GF(2)[X]$

In mathematica this $P$ can be found by

```
FieldIrreducible[GF[4],X]
```

which outputs

```
1 + X + X^{2}
```

The elements of $GF(4)$ can then be found by $0 \in GF(2)$, $1 \in GF(2)$ and let $w$ be a root of $P$ in GF(4), so that $1 + w + w^{2} = 0$ in $GF(4)$.
So $0, 1, w, w+1$ are the elements of $GF(4)$.

But $P \in GF[2]$ so $w^{2} = w+1$. So the elements of $GF(4)$ are $0, 1, w, 2^{2}$.

**Is it possible to use the Finite Fields package to define the elements of GF(4) in terms of the irreducible polynomial $P$?** If not, is there another way that anybody could think to do this?

---

If I have made any errors in my assumptions on how the construction of finite fields work, please let me know. thanks!

Comment: I'm not familiar with the package, but support for finite fields was added to version 13.3. Perhaps review the documentation and see if that's of any help to you. See guide/FiniteFields  Also see FiniteFields/tutorial/FiniteFields, for a package,  which shows examples involving GF[q], including various polynomial functions.